# Check if any input on the page is focused lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, document, lightning-locker

I want to **execute** some logic in specific moment(from my **LWC**) if **no Inputs** has the **focus** on my Page.
So I want to know if there is the **focus** on some **input** on the page ?
(Logic is executed from an Event Listener on "keypress")

The **LWC** is a part of **managed package**, so an idea with enabling  **Lightning Web Security** is not the case.

From **JavaScript** side, I would use  **[document.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement)**, to achieve this
See next question : [How do I find out which DOM element has the focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-dom-element-has-the-focus)

I see that `document.activeElement` is still available in [Locker API Viewer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer)

[image]

However I can not access the `document.activeElement` properties in my LWC.
And If I debug next line

```js
console.log(document.activeElement.toString());
```

I will get next output

```js
SecureObject: [object HTMLDivElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }
```

So it looks like [Lightning Locker](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_locker_service) **blocks** me from seeing the data from `document.activeElement`.

> SecureObject - secure wrapper for an object that is wrapped by Lightning Locker. When you see a SecureObject, it typically means that you don’t have access to the underlying object and its properties aren’t available.

Is there any other way to access `document.activeElement` ?
Or to find out if some DOM element has the **focus** ?

*Any help will be appreciated,

Thank you*

Comment: Are you using Locker Service? If so, have you tried switching to Lightning Web Security?

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks, I have enabled Lightning Web Security and now I can access the `document.activeElement` properties. However the LWC is included in Managed Package and I can't be sure that  Lightning Web Security will be enabled there. Are there any other ways ?

Comment: Not necessarily an answer, but try: `window.addEventListener('focusin', (event) => { this.activeElement = event.target });`; this should allow you to get an event whenever an element is focused. However, it may not always be the value you expect, and it probably still won't work outside your namespace.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks, However I always get the same result and I can't differentiate which focus is on simple element and which is on input. Ok, I now understand that I have not asked about it.  I need to know only when focus is on some of inputs on my page. I updated the question